# Fallback for display:none / visibility:hidden in case javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, fallback

Basically I initially set certain elements to `display: none;` and `visibility: hidden;` in my css file and that make them visible with help of jQuery. I was thinking, if users have javascript disabled, that would mean that they will not see any of these hidden elements at all. How could I create a sort of a fallback in order to display this content to browsers with disabled javascript?

Comment: Add an overridden CSS file inside `<noscript>` tags should work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your head, place something like :

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden_by_js_class {display: block;}
    </style>
</noscript>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/noscript):

> The HTML `<noscript>` Element defines a section of html to be inserted
>   if a script type on the page is unsupported or if scripting is
>   currently turned off in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  tag : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Javascript is On");
</script>
<noscript><span>Your Javascript is off</span></noscript>`
```